# SSIS Authentification with SharepointList data source

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2013, ssis-2012

I'm creating an SSIS Package that imports data from a SharePoint List, I've an authentification issue due to the SPCRED Component I think.
for the record I'm using a developement server in a domain whitch is different   from the Sharepoint One. So I do specifie this one "SharePoint Server DomainName" in my SPCRED[Her is my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR7b0.png) Because Ican't use my windows Credantials.
I verrified that with my credantials I've an admin role in the hole Sharepoint web site. when configuring my SharePoint List Source I've got all the columns I was Able to do the data mapping. but when executing the package it runs into an error  because of the authentification Here is the error:

> SSIS package "MyPackage.dtsx" starting.
>   Information: 0x4004300A at Liste FPDA, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
>   Error: 0xC0047062 at SharepointListName, SharepointListName [193]: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>   Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoap.GetListAndView(GetListAndViewRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListsService.ListsSoapClient.GetListAndView(String listName, String viewName)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.Adapter.ListsAdapter.GetSharePointFields(String listName, String viewId)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointUtility.ListServiceUtility.GetFields(Uri sharepointUri, NetworkCredential credentials, String listName, String viewName)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.GetAccessibleSharePointColumns(String sharepointUrl, String listName, String viewName)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.ValidateSharePointColumns()
>      at Microsoft.Samples.SqlServer.SSIS.SharePointListAdapters.SharePointListSource.Validate()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
>   Error: 0xC0047017 at Liste FPDA, SSIS.Pipeline: Liste FPDA failed validation and returned error code 0x80131501.
>   Error: 0xC004700C at Liste FPDA, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
>   Error: 0xC0024107 at Liste FPDA: There were errors during task validation.
>   SSIS package "MyPackage.dtsx"  finished: Failure.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, what helped me was setting the runtime credentials using the guide I've found [here](http://hownottoprogram.azurewebsites.net/?p=181)

> - Manually set to use Custom Credentials, then enter details of an account that has permissions to read & write to the target Sharepoint list
> - At run time, the account password set in the connection manager will not be used, it must be set by using package configurations.
> - Go to SSIS menu > Package Configurations
> - Enable package configurations if not done already
> - Click Add to create a new configuration
> - Select required configuration location, probably either XML file or SQL Server if available
> - Click next to select properties
> - In the tree of items to configure, expand Connection Managers > SharePoint Credential > Properties
> - Select UserName and Password properties, click Next
> - Set configuration name & click Finish
> - The Password value will not have been saved to the configuration destination because it is secured. You need to open the configuration location and manually set the Password value.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by adding Connection Parameters. Right click the SharePoint Credential and select "Parameterize..." from the pop-up menu. Then click the Property drop down and create parameters for both UserName and Password.